# Need an expert's opinion

Tags: document

I am relatively new to Sharepoint, and a bit daunted by the huge community that I now have available to me.  I come from using a CRM that had NO community support, and was locked down by the software maker.

I believe I'm getting as much as I can out of Sharepoint out of the box, and am wondering what else I might be able to accomplish with either 1) a tweek that I am unaware of or 2) custom programming.

What I am looking for is advice on how someone would set up their document workflows in the following situation:  In our office, documents arrive and are immediately scanned in by the frontdesk.  The frontdesk then uploads the file to a Sharepoint document library using the upload command, selecting the proper file folder into which to place the file.  Once uploaded, the file is given the proper attributes by completing several custom columns we have added in.

Alternatively, the frontdesk may at times go directly to the folder where the file will be located, then drags and drops the file from a local share.  Then they will use the Quick Edit grid to make changes to the item's properties.

I don't think there is much I can do to improve this first part.

The second part, however, is really where I have some questions about what a best practice should be.  We have a custom column entitled "Done", with two options:  "Done" and "Not Done".  When the document was saved to Sharepoint by the frontdesk, there were some documents that  were marked "Not Done".  These would be documents that need to be reviewed by another assistant in the office, in case that document needs any additional action.

Right now, I have a view set up to sample all the folders in the library (there are 600 folders, one for each client) and search for all files marked "not done".

I suppose my question is:  is there a better way, perhaps built into Sharepoint, that the frontdesk can set up the file to be reviewed by the secondary assistant?  Is there a workflow that could be used to...pass that file to someone?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint  Designer workflow for your required. You can add your condition for your column "**Done**" . After approval you can set change the value of your column.

Sample workflows you can check at:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/step-by-step-tutorial-creating-workflows-for-sharepoint-2010-step-115/

You can also check : http://approvalworkflow.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need a an approval workflow, which initiated either item add or item update.

in condition it will check if status is Done then complete the workflow.

But if Status is not Not Done then send the email to reviewer.

check this guide for workflow using deisgner.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/create-a-workflow-HA010100591.aspx